# Launch4j registry entries

Tags: launch4j

I am using launch4j to convert jar file to executable file,in that I am setting environment variables and registry entry ,but every time it is giving error may be syntax error is there .
this is my entry, i am trying to make http1 as custom url protocol. :

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http1]
%@="URL: http1 Protocol"%
"URL Protocol"=""%

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http1\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http1\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http1\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\http1\\test.exe\" %"
```

Please help as i am new to this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inno setup for making registry entries with the help of some script ,examples will be downloaded with the setup.
Hope this helps .
You can use this script :

; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

```
#define MyAppName "defaultapp"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "ACB"
#define MyAppURL "www.yz.com"
#define MyAppExeName "test.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{5AAF7999-80A7-40C4-A3A7-9CFA612CE2E3}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputBaseFilename=setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "H:\javafx\test.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{commonprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Registry] 
; Start "Software\My Company\My Program" keys under HKEY_CURRENT_USER 
; and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. The flags tell it to always delete the 
; "My Program" keys upon uninstall, and delete the "My Company" keys 
; if there is nothing left in them. 
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "defaultapp\Shell\Open\command"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "H:\javafx\test4.exe %1" ; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty 
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "defaultapp\DefaultIcon"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "H:\javafx\test.exe %1" ; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "defaultapp"; ValueType: string; ValueName: ""; ValueData: "URL:defaultapp Protocol" ; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty
Root: HKCR; Subkey: "epramaan"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "URL Protocol"; ValueData: "mack" ; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty  
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this mini-framework for creating .exe setup that make the custom protocol entries in registry file in windows machine . I have implemented this in my small app but how we add  icon in setup and add shortcut in start menu . Thank yo very much :)